# Master theorem solution for the case d=log_b(a)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence, divide-and-conquer

From Dasgupta's Algorithms: if the running time of a divide and conquer algorithm is described by the recurrence `T(n)=aT(n/b)+O(n^d)`, then its solution is:

1. `T(n)=O(n^d)` if `d>log_b(a)`
2. `T(n)=O(n^log_b(a))` if `d<log_b(a)`
3. `T(n)=O(n^d*log_2(n))` if `d=log_b(a)`

where each subproblem's size is decreasing by `b` in the next recursion call, `a` is the branching factor and `O((n/b^k)^d)` is the time for deviding and combining the subproblems on the level `k` for each subproblem.

Cases 1 and 2 are straightforward - they are taken from the geometric series formed when summing the work done at each level of the recursion tree, which is `a^k*O((n\b^k)^d)=O(n^d)*(a/b^d)^k`.

Where does the `log_2(n)` come up from in case 3? When `d=log_b(a)`, the ratio `a/b^d` equals 1, hence the sum of the series is `n^d*log_b(a)`, not `n^d*log_2(n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simpler example, first note that O(log n), O(log<sub>137</sub> n), and O(log<sub>16</sub> n) mean the same thing. The reason for this is that, by the change of basis formula for logarithms, for any fixed constant m we have

> log_m n = log n / log m = (1 / log m) · log n = O(log n).

The Master Theorem assumes that a, b, and d are constants. From the change of basis formula for logarithms, we have that

In that sense, O(n<sup>d</sup> log<sub>b</sub> n) = O(n<sup>d</sup> log n), since b is a constant here.

As a note, it’s unusual to see something written out as O(n<sup>d</sup> log<sub>2</sub> n), since the log base here doesn’t matter and just contributes to the (already hidden) constant factor.